# Can't get SyncAdapter to work in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-syncadapter

I've been trying to get a `SyncAdapter` to work. Man, what a ridiculously complicated mess. I don't even know where to begin, so I guess I'll just dump all the related code. If I put breakpoints pretty much everywhere in the code below, the following two things get called at startup (in this order):

- `StubContentProvider.OnCreate()`
- `AndroidApp.InitSyncService()` (called explicitly when my app starts up).

And that's it. Nothing else related to the `SyncAdapter` ever gets called (Seriously, I've put breakpoints at the top of every method of every class related to it.)

I've worked on this aspect of the app off and on for about a month and a half and at various times had it more functional than it is now, but I'm not sure how I made it less functional. I've tried tweaking every aspect of it. I've changed `ACCOUNT_TYPE` and `AUTHORITY` to various values. As I've read documentation and learned more, I'll tweak here and there, but it just doesn't seem to want to come together for me.

This is the last major piece of functionality for our app, so I can no longer keep putting this aside.

**AndroidApp.cs**

```
public static class AndroidApp
{

    public static string ACCOUNT_TYPE = "georgesmobile.android.backgroundservice";
    public static string ACCOUNT = "mobile";
    public static string AUTHORITY = "georgesmobile.android.provider";

    public static Account SyncAccount { get; private set; }

    public static void InitSyncService(Context context)
    {
        if (SyncAccount == null)
        {
            CreateSyncAccount(context);
            ContentResolver.SetIsSyncable(AndroidApp.SyncAccount, AndroidApp.AUTHORITY, 1);
            ContentResolver.SetSyncAutomatically(AndroidApp.SyncAccount, AndroidApp.AUTHORITY, true);
            Bundle bund = new Bundle();
            ContentResolver.AddPeriodicSync(AndroidApp.SyncAccount, AndroidApp.AUTHORITY, bund, 2);
        }
    }
    private static Account CreateSyncAccount(Context context)
    {
        SyncAccount = new Account(ACCOUNT, ACCOUNT_TYPE);
        AccountManager accountManager =  (AccountManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.AccountService);
        return SyncAccount;
    }
}
```

**StubContentProvider.cs**

```
[ContentProvider(new[] { "georgesmobile.android.provider" },
    Name = "georgesmobile.android.backgroundservice.StubContentProvider",
    Exported = false,
    Syncable = true)]
public class StubContentProvider : ContentProvider
{
    public override int Delete(global::Android.Net.Uri uri, string selection, string[] selectionArgs)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public override string GetType(global::Android.Net.Uri uri)
    {
        return "";
    }

    public override global::Android.Net.Uri Insert(global::Android.Net.Uri uri, ContentValues values)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override bool OnCreate()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override global::Android.Database.ICursor Query(global::Android.Net.Uri uri, string[] projection, string selection, string[] selectionArgs, string sortOrder)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override int Update(global::Android.Net.Uri uri, ContentValues values, string selection, string[] selectionArgs)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**GenericAccountService.cs**

```
[Service(Name = "georgesmobile.android.backgroundservice.GenericAccountService")]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" })]
[MetaData("android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator", Resource = "@xml/authenticator")]
public class GenericAccountService : Service
{
    private Authenticator _authenticator;

    public static Account GetAccount(string accountType)
    {
        return new Account(AndroidApp.ACCOUNT, AndroidApp.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        _authenticator = new Authenticator(this);
    }

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return _authenticator.IBinder;
    }
}
```

**SyncAdapter.cs**

```
[MetaData("android.content.SyncAdapter", Resource = "@xml/syncadapter")]
public class SyncAdapter : AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter 
{

    public override void OnPerformSync(global::Android.Accounts.Account account, Bundle extras, string authority, ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult)
    {
        BackgroundDataSync.Synchronize();
    }
}
```

**SyncService.cs**

```
[Service(Name = "georgesmobile.android.backgroundservice.SyncService", Exported = true)]
public class SyncService : Service
{
    private static SyncAdapter _syncAdapter;
    private static object _syncLock = new object();

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        lock (_syncLock)
        {
            _syncAdapter = new SyncAdapter(ApplicationContext, true);
        }
    }

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return _syncAdapter.SyncAdapterBinder;
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        return base.OnStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

**syncadapter.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<sync-adapter
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:contentAuthority="georgesmobile.android.provider"
        android:accountType="georgesmobile.android.backgroundservice"
        android:userVisible="true"
        android:supportsUploading="true"
        android:allowParallelSyncs="true"
        android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"/>
```

**authenticator.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<account-authenticator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:icon="@drawable/georgeslogo_icon"
    android:smallIcon="@drawable/georgeslogo_icon"
    android:label="@string/AppName"        
    android:accountType="georgesmobile.android.backgroundservice"/>
```

relevant `AndroidManifest.xml` (as generated by the compiler)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" package="georgesmobile.android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="Crackerjack">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCOUNT_MANAGER" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
  <application android:label="GeorgesMobile" android:icon="@drawable/georgeslogo_icon" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" android:name="mono.android.app.Application" android:debuggable="true">
    <receiver android:name="georgesmobile.android.backgroundservice.BootupReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="georgesmobile.android.backgroundservice.GenericAccountService">
      <meta-data android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <provider android:authorities="georgesmobile.android.provider" android:exported="false" android:name="georgesmobile.android.backgroundservice.StubContentProvider" android:syncable="true" />
    <service android:exported="true" android:name="georgesmobile.android.backgroundservice.SyncService">
      <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
    </service>
    <activity android:icon="@drawable/georgeslogo_icon" android:label="George's Inc" android:name="georgesmobile.android.views.HomeActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:icon="@drawable/georgeslogo_icon" android:label="George's Login" android:name="georgesmobile.android.views.LoginActivity" />
    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="2147483647" android:authorities="georgesmobile.android.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />
    <receiver android:name="mono.android.Seppuku">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="mono.android.intent.action.SEPPUKU" />
        <category android:name="mono.android.intent.category.SEPPUKU.georgesmobile.android" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Hey, did you manage to solve this problem at the end? I think I'll just give up and write a background service instead. It's just too much work!

Comment: @aloneguid Yes, I did finally get it working. It was a nightmare. John Miller at Xamarin was a huge help. The discussion was a bit long and involved. You can follow it here: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/16721/getting-a-syncadapter-to-work/p1